# Laravel 4 CronJob Keeps Running

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cron-task

I have a weird situation here.

I'm using Laravel 4 and linux crontab to run my cronjob, which is to send an email.

For testing purpose, I set every minute to run the cronjob so that I could get my result instantly.

crontab commands as below:

```
* * * * * php /xx/xx/xx/artisan user:active
```

actual output: received emails every minute, which is very good.

then I changed to

```
0 0 * * 0 php /xx/xx/xx/artisan user:active
```

actual output: I still received emails every minute, which is not supposed to be.

then I removed the crontab, just wipe the command and I still receiving email, unless I remove the recipient email address.

May I ask where I should check what's wrong?

**SOLUTION:**
the correct cronjob was created by another user where all the while I logged in as root.

Answer (score 0):

reboot the machine its likely still running in the background

Comment: do a ps -aux or something to findout what services are running

Comment: i tried 'service --status-all' and one of the list is '[+] cron'. does this means it's still running?